# Tika PDF to html truncates content of <li> tags which exceeds 254 characters

Tags: java, executable-jar, apache-tika

I am trying to convert a PDF document to HTML. It works fine but when it converts any list which contains more than 254 characters, it truncates the content and appends `...`.

Following is the code that I use to convert the document,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException, TikaException {
    byte[] file = Files.toByteArray(new File("src/main/java/test/test.pdf"));
    AutoDetectParser tikaParser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
    TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    handler.setResult(new StreamResult(out));
    ExpandedTitleContentHandler handler1 = new ExpandedTitleContentHandler(handler);
    tikaParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(file), handler1, new Metadata());
    System.out.println(new String(out.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));

}
```

I also noticed same issue with tika-app-2.7.0.jar and tika-app-2.6.0.jar.

Comment: I don't think we're truncating at the Tika level. If you're able to share the file with me privately, I can take a look: tallison AT apache DOT org

Comment: Another user ran into this and we figured out the following together: In that user's case, the <li/> elements that appeared to be truncated were PDF bookmarks. The bookmarks were truncated within the PDF (e.g. https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Character-limit-PDF-bookmarks-q37916.aspx).  Tika was doing the right thing, but the underlying PDF had truncated the bookmarks.  To turn off extraction of bookmarks, see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=109454066